# How can you discover what features in a dataset are predictive?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn, feature-detection

I'm working on a machine learning algorithm for the dataset available [here](http://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/data).

There are 26 columns of data. Most of it is pointless. How can I effectively and quickly determine what features are interesting - what features tell me one way or another whether a given URL is ephemeral or evergreen (which is the dependent variable in the dataset)? Are there intelligent, programmatic scikit learns ways of doing this or is it simply a case of graphic each feature against the dependent feature ('label', 26th column) and seeing what has an effect?

Surely there's a better way than this!

Can anyone help? :)

Edit : Some code for a classifier that I have found - how can I print out the weights given to each feature here ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from sklearn import metrics,preprocessing,cross_validation
  from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  import sklearn.linear_model as lm
  import pandas as p
  loadData = lambda f: np.genfromtxt(open(f,'r'), delimiter=' ')

  print "loading data.."
  traindata = list(np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,2])
  testdata = list(np.array(p.read_table('test.tsv'))[:,2])
  y = np.array(p.read_table('train.tsv'))[:,-1]

  tfv = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=3,  max_features=None, strip_accents='unicode',  
        analyzer='word',token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',ngram_range=(1, 2), use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1)

  rd = lm.LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', dual=True, tol=0.0001, 
                             C=1, fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1.0, 
                             class_weight=None, random_state=None)

  X_all = traindata + testdata
  lentrain = len(traindata)

  print "fitting pipeline"
  tfv.fit(X_all)
  print "transforming data"
  X_all = tfv.transform(X_all)

  X = X_all[:lentrain]
  X_test = X_all[lentrain:]

  print "20 Fold CV Score: ", np.mean(cross_validation.cross_val_score(rd, X, y, cv=20, scoring='roc_auc'))

  print "training on full data"
  rd.fit(X,y)
  pred = rd.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
  testfile = p.read_csv('test.tsv', sep="\t", na_values=['?'], index_col=1)
  pred_df = p.DataFrame(pred, index=testfile.index, columns=['label'])
  pred_df.to_csv('benchmark.csv')
  print "submission file created.."
```

Comment: This probably belongs on http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get most informative features for scikit-learn classifiers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116697/how-to-get-most-informative-features-for-scikit-learn-classifiers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many fitted scikit-learn estimators have an attribute `feature_importances_` (except linear models, which call it `coef_`) containing some kind of feature weights. Higher weights generally mean features contribute more to the final prediction, which can be interpreted as those features being more predictive.(*)

These attributes hold NumPy arrays, with shape either `(n_features,)` for binary classification, regression and non-linear models, or `(n_features, n_classes)` for multiclass linear models.

See the [document classification example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html) for how to use these attributes.

(*) All the usual caveats about overfitting apply: in a bad model, the wrong features may get the higher weights.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have added some code for a Logistic regression to my response - am I right in saying that I could just print rd.feature_importances_ and it would give me a list of how much each feature effected the classifier or have I misconstrued. Apologies, I am still a beginner at Machine Learning and Python :)

Comment: @SimonKiely Logistic regression is a linear model, so you need `coef_`. Please read the example script I linked to.