# SkLearn Multinomial NB: Extracting All Features

Tags: python, feature-extraction

I use MultinomialNB() classifier and TfidfVectorizer to build a binary model (have only 2 classes)
I want to print out and save to csv file the complete list of coef_ , features and labels.
What happens is I can print out features for one class only- it gives an error once i try to print for the second class. I understand it is because of the classes being binary? 
i have used the following code

index = 0
coef_features_c1_c2 = []

for feat, c1, c2 in zip(vector.get_feature_names(), clf.feature_count_[0], clf.feature_count_[1]):
    coef_features_c1_c2.append(tuple([clf.coef_[0][index], feat, c1, c2]))
    index+=1

for i in sorted(coef_features_c1_c2):
    print (i)

[How to get most informative features for scikit-learn classifier for different class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976362/how-to-get-most-informative-features-for-scikit-learn-classifier-for-different-c)

my question is how to get all the features for both classes

Thank you