# How does MultinomialNB calculate probability predictions?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

`MultinomialNB` from scikit-learn is giving unexpected outputs for some simple use cases.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

docs = ['aa','aa','','','aa']
y    = np.array([1,1,1,1,2])

vec = CountVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(docs)
clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=1e-10).fit(X, y)
X_test = vec.transform(['aa'])
print(clf.predict_proba(X_test)[0, 0])
# >> 0.8
```

when I would expect 0.4 given that I understand P(y|X) to be approximated in this case as `P(x='aa'|y=1) * P(y=1) = 2/4 * 4/5 = 0.4`. So P(X) is ignored

Now, the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#multinomial-naive-bayes) and [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61586946/how-to-calculate-feature-log-prob-in-the-naive-bayes-multinomialnb) make me think the calculation is really `P(x='aa'| all words in y=1 samples) * P(y=1) = 2/2 * 4/5 = 0.8`.

However, this doesn't work if you run the same example above but with `docs = ['aa','aa','bb','bb','aa']`, which gives 0.6666667 as an output.

In this new case, I would expect both formulas to give `(2/4 * 2/4) * 4/5 = 0.2`. I have `(2/4 * 2/4)` because the P(X|y) term, under the independence assumption, is the product of both having "aa" and not having "bb" when y=1.

Any clarification is appreciated.