# NLTK classifier for integer features?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk, text-classification, n-gram

I have integer-type features in my feature vector that NLTK’s `NaiveBayesClassifier` is treating as nominal values.

### Context

I am trying to build a language classifier using n-grams. For instance, the bigram ‘th’ is more common in English than French.

For each sentence in my training set, I extract a feature as follows: `bigram(th): 5` where 5 (example) represents the number of times the bigram ‘th’ appeared in the sentence.

When I try building a classifier with features like this and I check the most informative features, I realize that the classifier does not realize that such features are linear. For example, it might consider `bigram(ea): 4` as French, `bigram(ea): 5` as English and `bigram(ea): 6` as French again. This is quite arbitrary and does not represent the logic that a bigram is either more common in English or in French. This is why I need the integers to be treated as such.

### More thoughts

Of course, I could replace these features with features such as `has(th): True`. However, I believe this is a bad idea because both a French sentence with 1 instance of 'th' and an English sentence with 5 instances of 'th' will have the feature `has(th): True` which cannot differentiate them.

I also found [this relevant link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nltk-users/PapQfN4t2nk) but it did not provide me with the answer.

### Feature Extractor

My feature extractor looks like this:

```
def get_ngrams(word, n):
    ngrams_list = []
    ngrams_list.append(list(ngrams(word, n, pad_left=True, pad_right=True, left_pad_symbol='_', right_pad_symbol='_')))
    ngrams_flat_tuples = [ngram for ngram_list in ngrams_list for ngram in ngram_list]
    format_string = ''
    for i in range(0, n):
        format_string += ('%s')
    ngrams_list_flat = [format_string % ngram_tuple for ngram_tuple in ngrams_flat_tuples]
    return ngrams_list_flat

# Feature extractor
def get_ngram_features(sentence_tokens):
    features = {}
    # Unigrams
    for word in sentence_tokens:
        ngrams = get_ngrams(word, 1)
        for ngram in ngrams:
            features[f'char({ngram})'] = features.get(f'char({ngram})', 0) + 1
    # Bigrams
    for word in sentence_tokens:
        ngrams = get_ngrams(word, 2)
        for ngram in ngrams:
            features[f'bigram({ngram})'] = features.get(f'bigram({ngram})', 0) + 1
    # Trigrams
    for word in sentence_tokens:
        ngrams = get_ngrams(word, 3)
        for ngram in ngrams:
            features[f'trigram({ngram})'] = features.get(f'trigram({ngram})', 0) + 1
    # Quadrigrams
    for word in sentence_tokens:
        ngrams = get_ngrams(word, 4)
        for ngram in ngrams:
            features[f'quadrigram({ngram})'] = features.get(f'quadrigram({ngram})', 0) + 1
    return features
```

### Feature Extraction Example

```
get_ngram_features(['test', 'sentence'])
```

Returns:

```
{'char(c)': 1,
 'char(e)': 4,
 'char(n)': 2,
 'char(s)': 2,
 'char(t)': 3,
 'bigram(_s)': 1,
 'bigram(_t)': 1,
 'bigram(ce)': 1,
 'bigram(e_)': 1,
 'bigram(en)': 2,
 'bigram(es)': 1,
 'bigram(nc)': 1,
 'bigram(nt)': 1,
 'bigram(se)': 1,
 'bigram(st)': 1,
 'bigram(t_)': 1,
 'bigram(te)': 2,
 'quadrigram(_sen)': 1,
 'quadrigram(_tes)': 1,
 'quadrigram(ence)': 1,
 'quadrigram(ente)': 1,
 'quadrigram(est_)': 1,
 'quadrigram(nce_)': 1,
 'quadrigram(nten)': 1,
 'quadrigram(sent)': 1,
 'quadrigram(tenc)': 1,
 'quadrigram(test)': 1,
 'trigram(_se)': 1,
 'trigram(_te)': 1,
 'trigram(ce_)': 1,
 'trigram(enc)': 1,
 'trigram(ent)': 1,
 'trigram(est)': 1,
 'trigram(nce)': 1,
 'trigram(nte)': 1,
 'trigram(sen)': 1,
 'trigram(st_)': 1,
 'trigram(ten)': 1,
 'trigram(tes)': 1}
```

Comment: Did you try turning the occurrences into nominal features by categorizing them compared to a threshold? (i.e. th<5, th>=5)

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos That's not ideal because it's difficult to determine the best thresholds for all n-grams

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos Your name sounds Greek. Actually, the exact problem I'm working on involves the Greek language. You can take a look here: https://github.com/hb20007/greek-dialect-classifier/blob/master/3-Building-the-Classifier.ipynb

Comment: That looks fun. I don't know how stuck you are with naive Bayes, but I'm pretty certain other simple learning algorithms such as random forest will do the threshold picking on their own.

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos Would decision trees work for this kind of problem? The total number of possible uni, bi, tri and quadrigrams in a language is massive. I can't imagine a decision tree being constructed with all of these.

Comment: Applying some sort of prefiltering would definitely help (i.e. same or similar occurrence counts between languages could be dismissed)

Comment: @KonstantinosKokos That's possible, I could focus on the most discriminating n-grams. I wonder if it's the best way to go about doing this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168002/discussion-between-konstantinoskokos-and-hb20007).

Comment: Could you post your feature extraction function in the question?

Comment: @alvas Just edited the question to add my feature extractor

Comment: Honestly, that's some nutty extractor =)

Comment: As well as/instead of featurizing for each possible value n of `bigram(xx): n` in a sentence, just compute the character density: 2*number of bigrams 'xx' / number of chars in sentence. And yes, random forests will discover both the features and the threshold values which give maximal improvement in the impurity metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

It's easier to use other libraries for this purpose. It's easier to do something like this https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk with `sklearn` using a custom analyzer, e.g. `CountVectorizer(analyzer=preprocess_text)`

For example:

```
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from nltk import everygrams

def sent_process(sent):
    return [''.join(ng) for ng in everygrams(sent.replace(' ', '_ _'), 1, 4) 
            if ' ' not in ng and '\n' not in ng and ng != ('_',)]

sent1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog."
sent2 = "Mr brown jumps over the lazy fox."
sent3 = 'Mr brown quickly jumps over the lazy dog.'
sent4 = 'The brown quickly jumps over the lazy fox.'

with StringIO('\n'.join([sent1, sent2])) as fin:
    # Override the analyzer totally with our preprocess text
    count_vect = CountVectorizer(analyzer=sent_process)
    count_vect.fit_transform(fin)
count_vect.vocabulary_ 


train_set = count_vect.fit_transform([sent1, sent2])

# To train the classifier
clf = MultinomialNB() 
clf.fit(train_set, ['pos', 'neg']) 

test_set = count_vect.transform([sent3, sent4])
clf.predict(test_set)
```

## Cut-away

Firstly, there's really no need to explicitly label the `char(...)`, `unigram(...)`, `bigram(...)`, `trigram(...)` and `quadrigram(...)` part to the features.

The feature set are just dictionary keys and you can use the actual ngram tuple as the keys, e.g.

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk import ngrams, word_tokenize

features = Counter(ngrams(word_tokenize('This is a something foo foo bar foo foo sentence'), 2))
```

[out]:

```
>>> features
Counter({('This', 'is'): 1,
         ('a', 'something'): 1,
         ('bar', 'foo'): 1,
         ('foo', 'bar'): 1,
         ('foo', 'foo'): 2,
         ('foo', 'sentence'): 1,
         ('is', 'a'): 1,
         ('something', 'foo'): 1})
```

As for ngrams of several orders, you can use `everygrams()`, e.g.

```
from nltk import everygrams

sent = word_tokenize('This is a something foo foo bar foo foo sentence')
Counter(everygrams(sent, 1, 4))
```

[out]:

```
Counter({('This',): 1,
         ('This', 'is'): 1,
         ('This', 'is', 'a'): 1,
         ('This', 'is', 'a', 'something'): 1,
         ('a',): 1,
         ('a', 'something'): 1,
         ('a', 'something', 'foo'): 1,
         ('a', 'something', 'foo', 'foo'): 1,
         ('bar',): 1,
         ('bar', 'foo'): 1,
         ('bar', 'foo', 'foo'): 1,
         ('bar', 'foo', 'foo', 'sentence'): 1,
         ('foo',): 4,
         ('foo', 'bar'): 1,
         ('foo', 'bar', 'foo'): 1,
         ('foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'): 1,
         ('foo', 'foo'): 2,
         ('foo', 'foo', 'bar'): 1,
         ('foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo'): 1,
         ('foo', 'foo', 'sentence'): 1,
         ('foo', 'sentence'): 1,
         ('is',): 1,
         ('is', 'a'): 1,
         ('is', 'a', 'something'): 1,
         ('is', 'a', 'something', 'foo'): 1,
         ('sentence',): 1,
         ('something',): 1,
         ('something', 'foo'): 1,
         ('something', 'foo', 'foo'): 1,
         ('something', 'foo', 'foo', 'bar'): 1})
```

A clean way to extract the features you want:

```
def sent_vectorizer(sent):
    return [''.join(ng) for ng in everygrams(sent.replace(' ', '_ _'), 1, 4) 
            if ' ' not in ng and ng != ('_',)]
Counter(sent_vectorizer('This is a something foo foo bar foo foo sentence'))
```

[out]:

```
Counter({'o': 9, 's': 4, 'e': 4, 'f': 4, '_f': 4, 'fo': 4, 'oo': 4, 'o_': 4, '_fo': 4, 'foo': 4, 'oo_': 4, '_foo': 4, 'foo_': 4, 'i': 3, 'n': 3, 'h': 2, 'a': 2, 't': 2, 'hi': 2, 'is': 2, 's_': 2, '_s': 2, 'en': 2, 'is_': 2, 'T': 1, 'm': 1, 'g': 1, 'b': 1, 'r': 1, 'c': 1, 'Th': 1, '_i': 1, '_a': 1, 'a_': 1, 'so': 1, 'om': 1, 'me': 1, 'et': 1, 'th': 1, 'in': 1, 'ng': 1, 'g_': 1, '_b': 1, 'ba': 1, 'ar': 1, 'r_': 1, 'se': 1, 'nt': 1, 'te': 1, 'nc': 1, 'ce': 1, 'Thi': 1, 'his': 1, '_is': 1, '_a_': 1, '_so': 1, 'som': 1, 'ome': 1, 'met': 1, 'eth': 1, 'thi': 1, 'hin': 1, 'ing': 1, 'ng_': 1, '_ba': 1, 'bar': 1, 'ar_': 1, '_se': 1, 'sen': 1, 'ent': 1, 'nte': 1, 'ten': 1, 'enc': 1, 'nce': 1, 'This': 1, 'his_': 1, '_is_': 1, '_som': 1, 'some': 1, 'omet': 1, 'meth': 1, 'ethi': 1, 'thin': 1, 'hing': 1, 'ing_': 1, '_bar': 1, 'bar_': 1, '_sen': 1, 'sent': 1, 'ente': 1, 'nten': 1, 'tenc': 1, 'ence': 1})
```

## In Long

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to change the hardcoded manner of how the `NaiveBayesClassifier` in NLTK works.

If we look at https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py#L185 , behind the scenes **NLTK is already counting the number of occurrence in the features.**

But note, it's counting the document frequency, not term frequency, i.e. **in that case regardless of how many times an element appears in the document, it counts as one**. There isn't a clean way without changing the NLTK code to add the value of each feature since it's hardcoded to do `+=1`, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py#L201

Comment: Indeed, sklearn's `MultinomialNB` classifier works for integer features. I vectorized my data, built the classifier, then checked the most informative features using https://stackoverflow.com/a/11140887/4304516